# Get rerouted request (module, controller, action names) in plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins

I've got a plugin (dispatchLoopStartup) that checks if a user is allowed to access certain sections of a site without being logged in. If they try and access a restricted section they get forwarded to the login page, like this:

```
$request->setControllerName('login');
$request->setActionName('cms');
```

I've got another plugin (preDispatch) that retrieves data from the database based on the current action. When the request has been forwarded to a different action this plugin still reads the request as it was before it was forwarded.

How can I get the updated request in the 2nd plugin?

Comment: I emulated your situation, and changed the controller and action name in a `dispatchLoopStartup()` plugin, and when accessing the controller and action name is a second `preDispatch()` plugin, it displayed the updated controller name and action, rather than the one in the URL.  What version of ZF are you running?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I'm running 1.11.0dev, php 5.3.6

Comment: Can you post some of the code for both plugins and perhaps I could try with what you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly error on my part. I was accessing the module/controller/action via `$request->getParams()` rather than :

```
echo $request->getModuleName().'/'
    .$request->getControllerName().'/'
    .$request->getActionName().'/';
```

getParams() returned the params pre forward which is why I was being confused.